# Не работает RegExp

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Есть (вместо ## - число):

```
"page_item page-item-##"
```

Есть скрипт с RegExp:

```
tags[i].className.match(/page\witem\spage.item.\d+/)
```

Вопрос в том, что не хочет отрабатывать. При том, что при online проверке RegExp отрабатывает корректно. В чем ошибка?

*Обновление*

Спасибо за ответы. Все более прозаично.
Есть скрипт (не мой):

```
function highlight(){
    var tags=document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for(i in tags){
        if(tags[i].className.match(/page\witem\spage.item.\d+/){
            if(document.location.href==tags[i].firstChild.href){
                tags[i].className += " activ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но на выходе activ к классу не добавляется. Притом при всем, что, если RegExp заменить на "page_item page-item-(число)", то добавляется. Парадокс, однако.

P.S. Скрипт должен проверять ссылки `<a href="page_item page-item-(число)##">` в меню и добавлять к существующему классу active после цифры.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рег. выражение у вас б-м нормальное (хотя я бы добавил начало и конец строки и не использовал бы точку), но не понятно какой результат вам нужен.

Если вы хотите проверить соответствие строки шаблону то нужно написать:

```
/page\witem\spage.item.\d+/.test('page_item page-item-33')
```

Если хотите получить цифры:

```
"page_item page-item-33".match(/^page\witem\spage.item.(\d+)$/)
```

*Обновление*

в таком случае вам лучше заменить match на test как написано ниже:

```
if (/page\witem\spage.item.\d+/.test(tags[i].className))
```

Comment: kolpak, спасибо больше - именно то, что было необходимо.

Answer (score 2):

Я проверил так

```
"page_item page-item-33".match(/page\witem\spage.item.\d+/)
```

Работает нормально. Отсюдова вывод - проверяйте содержимое `tags[i].className`.